# How to perform single operation on Multiple columns of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df
>>>                                     TSLA             MSFT
2017-05-15 00:00:00+00:00                320              68
2017-05-16 00:00:00+00:00                319              69
2017-05-17 00:00:00+00:00                314              61
2017-05-18 00:00:00+00:00                313              66
2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00                316              62
2017-05-22 00:00:00+00:00                314              65
2017-05-23 00:00:00+00:00                310              63


max_idx = df.idxmax() # returns index of max value
>>> TSLA    2017-05-15 00:00:00+00:00
>>> MSFT    2017-05-16 00:00:00+00:00

max_value = df.max() # returns max value
>>> TSLA = 320
>>> MSFT = 69

def pct_change(first, second):  # pct chg formula
    return (second-first) / first*100.00
```

I want to get percent change between `max_value` and with each consecutive value starting from `max_idx` (`df.loc[max_idx:]`) for both columns. Just to  ensure that,
the percent change is not below 5%.

```
Example: 
for TSLA:  320 with 319 = 2%       for MSFT: 69 with 61 = 4%
           320 with 314 = 4%                 69 with 66 = 5% 
           320 with 313 = 5%                 69 with 62 = 10%
```

**Edit:** If you find it difficult to answer, i can be happy with just a reference to what type of function or method i shall use for such operations.

> Note: I just want to ensure that percent change isn't below 5%.

Comment: Can you give your expected output? Also I don't see all those numbers match. For instance shouldn't `(69-61)/61 == 0.101`?

Comment: % changes are just for the example purpose, i just want the way, of how to perform such operation, and output can be anything, just it shall acknowledge that the % change is below 5% @Psidom

Comment: @JohnGalt its just for the example purpose.

Comment: Do `100.*(1 - df/df.max())` and then limit with `df.idxmax()`?

Comment: So you want the answer as something like `TSLA: True, MSFT: False` for instance.

Comment: @Psidom no, when iterating through all the combinations for each column as shown in example, if % chg. is less than 5% for any of the value in that column, return false for TSLA same applies to MSFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about your true/false conditions, but I think you need something like this, thanks to @JohnGalt:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ((1 - x/x.max()) > 0.05).all())
```

Or using your logic:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ((x[x.idxmax()]-x)/x[x.idxmax()]*100>5).all())
```

Output:

```
TSLA    False
MSFT    False
dtype: bool
```

Let's look at one column,

John's formula:

```
1 - df.TSLA/df.TSLA.max()
```

Returns:

```
2017-05-15 00:00:00+00:00    0.000000
2017-05-16 00:00:00+00:00    0.003125
2017-05-17 00:00:00+00:00    0.018750
2017-05-18 00:00:00+00:00    0.021875
2017-05-19 00:00:00+00:00    0.012500
2017-05-22 00:00:00+00:00    0.018750
2017-05-23 00:00:00+00:00    0.031250
Name: TSLA, dtype: float64
```

If all of those values are greater than 5 return True, else return False.

My original formula works also, just a bit more calculation to do the same thing that John formula does.
Lastly, use lambda function to apply this formula to each column independently.

Comment: How about `((1 - df/df.max()) > 0.05).all()` or even `(df/df.max() < 0.95).all()`?

Comment: @ScottBoston Can you please elaborate, its difficult to understand such long linear equation.

Comment: @ScottBoston I appreciate it. Since am new to pandas, it will take sometime to figure out your answer, Thanks! :)

Comment: @JohnGalt, Thanks for helping to make the answer look more simpler!

Comment: You are welcome.  Happy coding. Pandas docs are actually pretty good.  Read the [cookbook section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html) to get a good jump start.