# Compare two columns and see the difference

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame df1 with one of the columns being "id":

```
id
fgh56t
67df59
534we5
780sda
```

I have another data frame df2 with extensive list of all ids in a column "id" and its names in a column "names":

```
id        names
fgh56t    abc
df439k    pqr
67df59    lmn
56432o    xyz
534we5    rst
780sda    cde
```

The size of the df2 will obviously be more than the size of the df1, because df2 contains all the ids possible. I want to create a resultant data frame df3 containing all ids and their names that aren't present in df1, but are present in df2. So result should look like:

```
id        name
df439k    pqr
56432o    xyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to construct a boolean series and subset:

```
df2[~df2.id.isin(df1.id)]

#       id  names
#1  df439k  pqr
#3  56432o  xyz
```

Comment: I have similar question, can you please look into it? nobody answered it yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511223/how-to-perform-single-operation-on-multiple-columns-of-dataframe

Comment: @BlueQuant, please don't spam all these answers, someone will look at your question in due time.

Answer (score 2):

Also, using `query` method, you can

```
In [95]: df2.query('id not in @df1.id')
Out[95]:
       id names
1  df439k   pqr
3  56432o   xyz
```