# Filter Pandas Series of datetimes through another Series of datetimes

Tags: python, pandas

Assume there are two Pandas `Series` (or `DataFrames`) both containing different `datetime` values. For example one series/frame containing messages and another one containing specific events. Now I would be interested in filtering out all messages which where posted right after *(meaning: within `n`-minutes after the event)* any event occured. How could I do that using Pandas?

*(Besides using two wrapped `for`-loops, I am hoping for something more panda-ish and maybe more efficient. Like using `groupby` or similar.)*

Some sample data could be:

```
import pandas as pd
messages = pd.DataFrame([
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:00:00"), "non-relevant msg 1"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:02:11"), "non-relevant msg 2"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:03:30"), "relevant msg 1"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:04:30"), "relevant msg 2"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:10:11"), "non-relevant msg 3"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 10:00:15"), "relevant again 1"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 10:03:15"), "relevant again 2"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 10:07:00"), "non-relevant msg 4"],
], columns=["created_at", "text"])
events = pd.Series([
    pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:02:59"),
    pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 10:00:00"),
])
n = pd.Timedelta("5min")
```

Which should give the following output:

```
output = pd.DataFrame([
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:03:30"), "relevant msg 1"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 09:04:30"), "relevant msg 2"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 10:00:15"), "relevant again 1"],
    [pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 10:03:15"), "relevant again 2"],
], columns=["created_at", "text"])
```

Comment: would you like show us some sample data

Comment: This is a typical question where example data sets (5-10 rows) are needed to make sure we onderstand you correctly both through your text as visually through the data. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to make a good reproducible `pandas` questions

Comment: @Erfan Sure, thank you for the link. I added some random sample data. I hope that makes my question more clear and also easier to parse as a reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I am hoping for something more panda-ish and maybe more efficient"*. Yes there's a more efficient way of getting your expected result by using `numpy` and `pandas` functionality's.

Party inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas/44601120#44601120) answer.

```
a = messages['created_at'].to_numpy()
bh = (events + n).to_numpy()
bl = events.to_numpy()

i, j = np.where((a[:, None] >= bl) & (a[:, None] <= bh))

messages.loc[i].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
           created_at              text
0 2000-01-01 09:03:30    relevant msg 1
1 2000-01-01 09:04:30    relevant msg 2
2 2000-01-01 10:00:15  relevant again 1
3 2000-01-01 10:03:15  relevant again 2
```

---

**Explanation**

Firs we create our `created_at` column to a numpy array and create our High and Low threshold of dates. Low = `events` and High = `events+n`.

Then we use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally go over the rows of our `messages` dataframe and store the indices of the rows which match with our condition where the datetime is between our thresholds. We store these indices in `i`.

Since we have our indices, we can simply use `.loc` to get our rows we want.

---

**Note**, if your pandas version is lower than 0.24.0, use `.values` instead of `to_numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand of your question but would be clearer if you posted what the answer should look like.

```
filtered_dfs = []
for event in events:
  condition = messages.created_at.between(event,event+n)
  filtered_dfs.append(messages.loc[condition])
```

This is how the two dfs look like:

```
#Output
           created_at            text
2 2000-01-01 09:03:30  relevant msg 1
3 2000-01-01 09:04:30  relevant msg 2 


           created_at              text
5 2000-01-01 10:00:15  relevant again 1
6 2000-01-01 10:03:15  relevant again 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, there should be a few ways to solve your problem - finding the efficient one is really the issue here.

I would probably use `apply` with a for-loop within, using a function like:

```
def follows_event(time, events=events, gap = pd.Timedelta('5min')):
    follows = False
    for i in list(events):
        if i < time and i+gap > time:
            follows = True
            break
    return follows
```

Once that's set up, you can simply use that to create a column that tells you if there's an event in the 5 minutes preceding the data, and do with that as you will.

```
df['follows_event'] = df.created_at.apply(follows_event)
```

If you want to remove those during that gap, use:

```
df_filtered = df[df.follows_event != True]
```