# Pandas merge two dataframes based on one column from one table lies in between two columns from another table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with ip address in one of the column and I want to add a new column
called "country" from another dataframe based on the location of ip address that lies between lower and upper ip address.

## Two dataframes

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ip': [0.1,2.5,3.5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'low_ip': [3,2,7,10],
                   'high_ip': [5,3,9,11],
                   'country': ['A','B','A','C']})

print(df1)
    ip
0  0.1
1  2.5
2  3.5

print(df2)
   low_ip  high_ip country
0       3        5       A
1       2        3       B
2       7        9       A
3      10       11       C
```

## Required

```
ip    country
0.1   NA
2.5   B   because: 2 <= 2.5 <= 3
3.5   A   because: 3 <= 3.5 <= 5
```

Comment: why are you using a pd Dataframe and not a dictionary?

Comment: This is just an example, actually dataframes contains lots of other columns as well.

Comment: I haven't tested performance or anything, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601120/2715819) to a pretty much identical question gives another method that might be better for large data sets, although it does re-index `df1`

Comment: @RishiG Thank for very useful link. Upvoted the given link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty way:

```
countries = []
for i in range(len(df1)):
    ip = df1.loc[i, 'ip']
    country = df2.query("low_ip <= @ip <= high_ip")['country'].to_numpy()

    if len(country) > 0:
        countries.append(country[0])
    else:
        countries.append('NA')

df1['country'] = countries

print(df1)

    ip country
0  0.1      NA
1  2.5       B
2  3.5       A
```