# Performing a merge in Pandas on a column containing a Python `range` or list-like

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, range

My question is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas) one made a few years ago.

I'm attempting a left join but one of the columns I want to join on needs to be a range value. It needs to be a range because expanding it would mean millions of new (and unnecessary) rows. Intuitively it seems possible using Python's `in` operator (as `x in range(y, z)` is very common) but would involve a nasty for loop and if/else block. There has to be a better way.

Here's a simple version of my data:

```
# These are in any order
sample = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['1b', '1a', '1a', '1b'],
    'col2': ['2b', '2b', '2a', '2a'],
    'col3': [42, 3, 21, 7]
})

# The 'look-up' table
look_up = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['1a', '1a', '1a', '1a', '1b', '1b', '1b', '1b'],
    'col2': ['2a', '2a', '2b', '2b', '2a', '2a', '2b', '2b'],
    'col3': [range(0,10), range(10,101), range(0,10), range(10,101), range(0,10), range(10,101), range(0,10), range(10,101)],
    'col4': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
})
```

I initially tried a merge to see if pandas would understand but there was a type mismatch error.

```
sample.merge(
    look_up,
    how='left',
    left_on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
    right_on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
)
# ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Reviewing the documentation for `pd.concat` looks like it will not give me result I want either. Rather than appending, I'm still trying to get a result like `merge`. I tried to follow the answer given to question I linked at the start but that didn't work either. It's **entirely** possible I misunderstood how to use `np.where` but also I'm hoping there is a solution that is a little less hacky.

Here's my attempt using `np.where`:

```
s1 = sample['col1'].values
s2 = sample['col2'].values
s3 = sample['col3'].values

l1 = look_up['col1'].values
l2 = look_up['col2'].values
l3 = look_up['col3'].values

i, j = np.where((s3[:, None] in l3) & (s2[:, None] == l2) & (s1[:, None] == l1))
result = pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([sample.values[i], look_up.values[j]]), 
    columns=sample.columns.append(look_up.columns)
)

len(result)  # returns 0
```

The result I want should look like this:

```
col1  col2 col3 col4
'1b'  '2b'   42  'h'
'1a'  '2b'    3  'c'
'1a'  '2a'   21  'b'
'1b'  '2a'    7  'e'
```

Comment: I do not know how big your frame is or the largest range (so they may not be the best option) but you can explode and merge: `sample.merge(look_up.explode('col3'), on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], how='left')`

Comment: I should have added the length currently is about 30 thousand rows. The largest range is 1,000 to 100,000 and the most common ones are probably 150 to 10,000. I think using `df.explode` might be the simplest, albiet brute-force option. Thanks!

Comment: @dlindsay `df.explode` is a fast, although very memory-heavy operation, but unless you encounter memory issues, it could be the simplest solution indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like ranges are pretty big, and you are working with integer vales, you can just compute the min, max:

```
columns = look_up.columns

look_up['minval'] = look_up['col3'].apply(min)
look_up['maxval'] = look_up['col3'].apply(max)
    
(sample.merge(look_up, on=['col1','col2'], how='left',
              suffixes=['','_'])
       .query('minval <= col3 <= maxval')
       [columns]
)
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2  col3 col4
1   1b   2b    42    h
2   1a   2b     3    c
5   1a   2a    21    b
6   1b   2a     7    e
```

Comment: Your use of `df.query` is exactly what I was missing. Thank you!