# How to expand a placeholder '*' with all possible values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72171357/15873043) features a dataframe with an asterisk `'*'` in some cells that would serve as a placeholder (or wildcard) for all values in the column. For example, the dataframe below,

```py
unique_values = list('ABC')
df = pd.DataFrame({0: list('AB*C*'), 
                   1: np.arange(5)+1})

# df
   0  1
0  A  1
1  B  2
2  *  3
3  C  4
4  *  5
```

would be equivalent to:

```py
# df2
   0  1
0  A  1
1  B  2
2  A  3
2  B  3
2  C  3
3  C  4
4  A  5
4  B  5
4  C  5
```

For further processing, it makes sense to make the placeholder explicit by replacing it with all the values it stands for.

My best attempt is to replace `*` with `unique_values`, then `explode` the column.
As neither `.replace('*', unique_values)` nor `.map({'*': unique_values})` would work (because the replacement is a `list`), I came up with:

```py
df2 = df.applymap(lambda x: unique_values if x == '*' else x).explode(0)
```

This is good enough for a single column, but it doesn't quite generalize to multiple columns; e.g., to turn

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({0: list('AB*C*'), 
                   1: np.arange(5)+1, 
                   2: list('*X*YZ')})

# df
   0  1  2
0  A  1  *
1  B  2  X
2  *  3  *
3  C  4  Y
4  *  5  Z
```

into

```py
   0  1  2
0  A  1  X
0  A  1  Y
0  A  1  Z
1  B  2  X
2  A  3  X
2  A  3  Y
2  A  3  Z
2  B  3  X
2  B  3  Y
2  B  3  Z
2  C  3  X
2  C  3  Y
2  C  3  Z
3  C  4  Y
4  A  5  Z
4  B  5  Z
4  C  5  Z
```

it's possible to replace the asterisk in each column with the respective `unique_values` and then explode, again, each column in turn,

```py
def expand_wildcard(col):
    unique_values = [x for x in col.unique() if x != '*']
    return col.apply(lambda x: unique_values if x == '*' else x)

df.apply(expand_wildcard).explode(0).explode(2)
```

which would become increasingly unwieldy. Is there a more pandaesque/vectorized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method could be to replace with a `set` and use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```
df2 = df.replace(pd.Series({c: {'*': set(df[c]).difference(['*'])} for c in df}))
from functools import reduce
df3 = reduce(lambda a,b: a.join(b), (df2[[c]].explode(c) for c in df2))
```

output:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  1  Y
0  A  1  Z
0  A  1  X
1  B  2  X
2  A  3  Y
2  A  3  Z
2  A  3  X
2  C  3  Y
2  C  3  Z
2  C  3  X
2  B  3  Y
2  B  3  Z
2  B  3  X
3  C  4  Y
4  A  5  Z
4  C  5  Z
4  B  5  Z
```