# Adding rows based on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, databricks

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| Index | Year | Month | Fruit | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021 | 03 | Apple | 2 |
| 1 | 2021 | 03 | Orange | 3 |
| 2 | 2021 | 03 | Mango | 4 |
| 3 | 2021 | 04 | Apple | 1 |
| 4 | 2021 | 04 | Mango | 2 |
| 5 | 2021 | 05 | Apple | 1 |

Let's say that Apple, Orange and Mango are the only fruits I am interested in.

The dataframe is formed such that if the count for a fruit (in a month and year) is 0, it won't show up as a record. I want to add the missing fruit row to the dataframe with count column value = 0. In short, I want each of the 3 fruits to show up for the year and month irrespective of the count being 0. So I want it to look like this:

| Index | Year | Month | Fruit | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021 | 03 | Apple | 2 |
| 1 | 2021 | 03 | Orange | 3 |
| 2 | 2021 | 03 | Mango | 4 |
| 3 | 2021 | 04 | Apple | 1 |
| x | 2021 | 04 | Orange | 0 |
| 4 | 2021 | 04 | Mango | 2 |
| 5 | 2021 | 05 | Apple | 1 |
| x | 2021 | 05 | Orange | 0 |
| x | 2021 | 05 | Mango | 0 |

Appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this.

Comment: I had a similar question a while back that could be relevant: [How to expand a placeholder '*' with all possible values in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72188079/how-to-expand-a-placeholder-with-all-possible-values-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pyjanitor`'s [`complete`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) to fill the missing rows:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

import janitor
data = '''Index Year    Month   Fruit   Count
0   2021    03  Apple   2
1   2021    03  Orange  3
2   2021    03  Mango   4
3   2021    04  Apple   1
4   2021    04  Mango   2
5   2021    05  Apple   1'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\t', index_col='Index')

df = df.complete('Fruit', ['Year', 'Month']).fillna(0, downcast='infer').sort_values(['Year', 'Month', 'Fruit'])
```

Output:

|  | Year | Month | Fruit | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021 | 3 | Apple | 2 |
| 2 | 2021 | 3 | Mango | 4 |
| 1 | 2021 | 3 | Orange | 3 |
| 3 | 2021 | 4 | Apple | 1 |
| 4 | 2021 | 4 | Mango | 2 |
| 6 | 2021 | 4 | Orange | 0 |
| 5 | 2021 | 5 | Apple | 1 |
| 8 | 2021 | 5 | Mango | 0 |
| 7 | 2021 | 5 | Orange | 0 |

Comment: you can use `fill_value` as well in `complete`: ``df.complete('Fruit', ('Year', 'Month'), fill_value = 0)``

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Categorical` to add `Fruit` as a category

```py
Year = [2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021]
Month = ["03","03", "03","04","04","05"]
Fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Mango", "Apple", "Mango", "Apple"]
Count = [2,3,4,1,2,1]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Year":Year, "Month":Month, "Fruit":Fruit, "Count":Count})

df['Fruit'] = pd.Categorical(df['Fruit'], categories=df['Fruit'].unique())
df = df.groupby(['Year','Month','Fruit'], as_index=False).first()
df['Count'] = df.Count.fillna(0).astype(int)
df
```

Output:

```
Year    Month   Fruit   Count
0   2021    03  Apple   2
1   2021    03  Orange  3
2   2021    03  Mango   4
3   2021    04  Apple   1
4   2021    04  Orange  0
5   2021    04  Mango   2
6   2021    05  Apple   1
7   2021    05  Orange  0
8   2021    05  Mango   0
```