Conditional cross join/Cartesian product two data sets
I have two sets of data about an airport: one on arriving flights (df_arrivals with 10 rows) and one on departing flights (df_departures with 10 rows). I would like to find all acceptable connecting flights.
Assuming a stopover of fewer than 4 hours is acceptable, that means finding all combinations of flights under the condition time delta < 4 hours. I first cross join/Cartesian product the two tables (getting 100 rows) and then filter the resulting DataFrame (getting 19 rows). Unfortunately, this method is too computationally demanding for the actual data (about a quarter of a million rows for arrivals and departures respectively) due to the number of combinations by cross join (numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError).
Is there a way to apply conditions while cross joining two tables?
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df_arrivals = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\df_arrivals.csv",
                          parse_dates=["Arriving time"])
df_departures = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\df_departures.csv",
                            parse_dates=["Departing time"])

df = pd.merge(df_arrivals, df_departures, how="cross")

condition = (df["Departing time"] - df["Arriving time"] >= datetime.timedelta(
    hours=0)) & (df["Departing time"] - df["Arriving time"]
                 < datetime.timedelta(hours=4))

df = df[condition]

Input:



Arriving flight
Arriving time




A1
2024-08-21 01:00


A2
2024-08-21 03:00


A3
2024-08-21 05:00


A4
2024-08-21 07:00


A5
2024-08-21 09:00


A6
2024-08-21 11:00


A7
2024-08-21 13:00


A8
2024-08-21 15:00


A9
2024-08-21 17:00


A10
2024-08-21 19:00






Departing flight
Departing time




D1
2024-08-21 02:00


D2
2024-08-21 04:00


D3
2024-08-21 06:00


D4
2024-08-21 08:00


D5
2024-08-21 10:00


D6
2024-08-21 12:00


D7
2024-08-21 14:00


D8
2024-08-21 16:00


D9
2024-08-21 18:00


D10
2024-08-21 20:00



Output:



Arriving flight
Arriving time
Departing flight
Departing time




A1
2024-08-21 01:00
D1
2024-08-21 02:00


A1
2024-08-21 01:00
D2
2024-08-21 04:00


A2
2024-08-21 03:00
D2
2024-08-21 04:00


A2
2024-08-21 03:00
D3
2024-08-21 06:00


A3
2024-08-21 05:00
D3
2024-08-21 06:00


A3
2024-08-21 05:00
D4
2024-08-21 08:00


A4
2024-08-21 07:00
D4
2024-08-21 08:00


A4
2024-08-21 07:00
D5
2024-08-21 10:00


A5
2024-08-21 09:00
D5
2024-08-21 10:00


A5
2024-08-21 09:00
D6
2024-08-21 12:00


A6
2024-08-21 11:00
D6
2024-08-21 12:00


A6
2024-08-21 11:00
D7
2024-08-21 14:00


A7
2024-08-21 13:00
D7
2024-08-21 14:00


A7
2024-08-21 13:00
D8
2024-08-21 16:00


A8
2024-08-21 15:00
D8
2024-08-21 16:00


A8
2024-08-21 15:00
D9
2024-08-21 18:00


A9
2024-08-21 17:00
D9
2024-08-21 18:00


A9
2024-08-21 17:00
D10
2024-08-21 20:00


A10
2024-08-21 19:00
D10
2024-08-21 20:00




kindly attach the expected output dataframe

Hi @sammywemmy I have added the output table to the question.

Unfortunately, the conditional_join function of pyjanitor gives the following error when applied to the actual data. numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 59.9 GiB for an array with shape (8037273074,) and data type int64 Could it be the function attempted to create an intermediate array akin to the following answer? stackoverflow.com/a/44601120/13516718

A lead: "The three-dimensional array, diff, is a consequence of broadcasting, not a necessity for the calculation. Large data sets will generate a large intermediate array that is computationally inefficient. Instead, if each observation is calculated individually using a Python loop around the code in the two-dimensional example above, a much smaller array is used." Source: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

that is expected.  conditional_join does create an intermediate array - it relies on numpy - if however your data is very large or there is significant gaps between the data, or you dont have enough memory then you likely will get that error message. On my local machine, I can create an array of size 8037273074, but that is not good enough. TLDR - share some more info about your data and let's see if you can prune the data before merging or find some other route

also, you can give polars or duckdb a go; it may be more performant for your use case

Many thanks @sammywemmy. Your comment helps me understand the bottleneck. I need to find a way to mask the actual data ... more googling! Meanwhile, I will try to prune the data early (which probably limits flexibility in analysis) as well as upgrade my laptop and/or access high performance computing.

IIUC, you can use pd.merge_asof with a tolerance:
df_arrivals['Arriving time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_arrivals['Arriving time'])

df_departures['Departing time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_departures['Departing time'])

pd.merge_asof(df_arrivals, df_departures, 
              left_on = 'Arriving time', 
              right_on = 'Departing time', 
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta(hours=4), 
              direction='forward')

Output:
  Arriving flight       Arriving time Departing flight      Departing time
0              A1 2024-08-21 01:00:00               D1 2024-08-21 02:00:00
1              A2 2024-08-21 03:00:00               D2 2024-08-21 04:00:00
2              A3 2024-08-21 05:00:00               D3 2024-08-21 06:00:00
3              A4 2024-08-21 07:00:00               D4 2024-08-21 08:00:00
4              A5 2024-08-21 09:00:00               D5 2024-08-21 10:00:00
5              A6 2024-08-21 11:00:00               D6 2024-08-21 12:00:00
6              A7 2024-08-21 13:00:00               D7 2024-08-21 14:00:00
7              A8 2024-08-21 15:00:00               D8 2024-08-21 16:00:00
8              A9 2024-08-21 17:00:00               D9 2024-08-21 18:00:00
9             A10 2024-08-21 19:00:00              D10 2024-08-21 20:00:00


Thank you for the suggestion. However, instead of looking for the nearest "one" departing flight for each arriving flight, I would like to find "all" departing flights within 4 hours of each arriving flight. Any ideas?

@Howard Yeah... cartesian join is one way and not optimal efficiency.  I think there maybe a way using pyjanitor and conditional_join.  See this post.

Noted. Will look into the pyjanitor package.

Unfortunately, the conditional_join function of pyjanitor gives the following error when applied to the actual data.
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 59.9 GiB for an array with shape (8037273074,) and data type int64
Could it be the function attempted to create an intermediate array akin to the following answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601120/13516718
